# Is it possible to add pre-defined collections cannot be deleted / edited to Directus

Tags: directus

I wonder if I could Directus as a CMS back-end for my huge project.

This requires me to add pre-defined collections that cannot be deleted or edited. Also, I need to prevent users add new collections.

I couldn't find anything in the docs for now; since Directus is not invented the way I want; It is expected to be extendable as much as possible. So I think I need to edit -almost- the whole system.

I hope I can find someone to lead me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The Directus is having a **roles & permissions** module where you can define who can create/edit/update/read the collections as well as items inside it.

There are 2 default roles:

- Admin
- Public

Only admins can create & maintain collections. You can add additional roles and define permissions for it. More on roles: https://docs.directus.io/guides/roles.html

You can also ask Directus to skip specific database tables and don't manage those. If you need to read data from skipped tables, you can write custom endpoints.

You can check the Directus setup live at: https://www.directus.app

P.S. I've worked on Directus interfaces and my team is working on API. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Yes, I already got role things but I still need pre-defined collections since I plan to distribute it to many companies. Doing this for everyone manually is not possible. The Directus project is huge, knowing where to look before trying to change the code would be great.